# SQL - MS Access - search text between two known text string

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm looking to extract 3 text part of below string..

```
Requested Ship Date: 05/31/2016 Please charge shipping to: ups 1234 PO Number: po 1234
```

1. 05/31/2016
2. ups 1234
3. po 1234

Knowing that `Requested Ship Date:` and `Please charge shipping to:` and `PO Number:` never change..  but the character length of the second and third can change..

I'm not very good in SQL Access. I know that in Excel it would be easy with the right and find option.. but in Access?

Is there a way to find what's `right` of each `:` and then subtract the result?

Any ideas that can help me?

Comment: Is this for a query which will only be run from within an Access session?  Or might you also run it from an external connection (ADO or ODBC) to the Access database?

Comment: within an Access session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Split()` it would be easy to split the input string into pieces and extract the pieces you need.  Here is an example from the Access Immediate window.

```vb
YourString = "Requested Ship Date: 05/31/2016 Please charge shipping to: ups 1234 PO Number: po 1234"
astrPieces = Split(YourString, " ")

? astrPieces(3)
05/31/2016
? astrPieces(9)
1234
? astrPieces(13)
1234
```

However, `Split()` can't be used directly in Access SQL.  But, since your query will only be run within an Access session, you could create a VBA function which uses `Split()` and use that function in your query.

Here is an Immediate window example of such a function in action.

```vb
? GetShipData(YourString, "date")
05/31/2016
? GetShipData(YourString, "ups")
1234
? GetShipData(YourString, "po")
1234
```

So your query could be similar to this:

```sql
SELECT
    GetShipData([YourFieldName], "date") AS ship_date,
    GetShipData([YourFieldName], "ups") AS ups,
    GetShipData([YourFieldName], "po") AS po
FROM YourTable;
```

Here is the function I tested in the Immediate window example above:

```vb
Public Function GetShipData(ByVal pInput As String, ByVal pWhichItem As String) As String
    Dim astrPieces() As String
    Dim strReturn As String

    astrPieces = Split(pInput, " ")
    Select Case pWhichItem
    Case "date"
        strReturn = astrPieces(3)
    Case "ups"
        strReturn = astrPieces(9)
    Case "po"
        strReturn = astrPieces(13)
    Case Else
        strReturn = "fail" '<- figure out what you want here
    End Select
    GetShipData = strReturn
End Function
```

You will probably want to refine that function in case any of your input strings don't match the pattern of your question's sample string.